# The console is logging "Not Found 404" with Heroku link. What do I do to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, heroku, bootstrap-5

I am creating a CRUD app of my choice for an assignment; however, they didn't really explain what a HEROKU app link is.
In the notes, my instructor provided the link.
"https://ancient-taiga-31359.herokuapp.com/api/houses".

However, the console keeps logging that it isn't found.
POST https://ancient-taiga-31359.herokuapp.com/ 404 (Not Found)

His CRUD app was using houses, while mine is using rescues instead. Would it be okay to change the end of the link to rescues instead? I know that the sources on my HTML file are correct because it wouldn't link over to my JavaScript file.

[This is my JavaScript code with the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3my.png)

I've tried just logging into Heroku on my browser. I'm not really sure how to get it to work besides that though.
I'm really looking for a basic explanation for Heroku links in JavaScript code with AJAX, HTML, BootStrap, and jQuery. I'm pretty new at servers and apps so an explanation of how VSC and Heroku links work would be great too!

Here is the full length of my JavaScript code.

```
class RescueService{
    static url = 'https://ancient-taiga-31359.herokuapp.com';

    static getAllRescues(){
        return $.get(this.url);
    }
    static updateRescue(house){
        return $.ajax({
            url: this.url + `/${house._id}`,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(house),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'PUT'4

class DOMManager {
    static rescues;

    static getAllRescues(){
        RescueService.getAllRescues().then(rescues => this.render(rescues));
    }

    static createRescue(name){
        RescueService.createRescue(new Rescue(name))
        .then(() =>{
            return RescueService.getAllRescues();
        })
    }

    static deleteRescue(id){
        RescueService.deleteRescue(id)
            .then(() => RescueService.getAllRescues())
            .then(rescues => this.render(rescues));
    }
    
    static addAnimal(id) {
        for (let rescue of this.rescues) {
            if (rescue._id == id) {
                rescue.animals.push(new Animal($(`#${rescue._id}-animal-name`).val(), $(`#${rescue._id}-type-name`).val()));
                RescueService.updateRescue(rescue)
                    .then(() => RescueService.getAllRescues())
                    .then(rescues => this.render(rescues));
            }
        }
    }    
    

    static render(rescues) {
        $('#app').empty();
        if (Array.isArray(rescues)) {
            for (let rescue of rescues) {
                $('#app').prepend(
                `<div id="${rescue._id}" class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h2>${rescue.name}</h2>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DOMManager.deleteRescue(${rescue._id})">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm">
                                        <input type="text" id="${rescue._id}-animal-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Animal Name"></input>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm">
                                        <input type="text" id="${rescue._id}-type-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Type of Animal"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button id="${rescue._id} + new-type" onclick="DOMManager.addAnimal('${rescue._id}')" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                `
                );
                for (let animal of rescue.animals){
                    $(`#${rescue._id}`).find('.card-body').append(
                        `<p>
                            <span id="name-${animal._id}"> <strong>Animal: </strong> ${animal.name} </span>
                            <span id="name-${type._id}"> <strong>Type: </strong> ${animal.name} </span>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DOMManager.deleteRoom('${rescue._id}', '${animal._id}')">Delete Room</button>
                        </p>
                        `
                    )
                    .then(rescues => this.render(rescues));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '#create-new-rescue', () => {
    DOMManager.createRescue($('#new-rescue-name').val());
    $('#new-rescue-name').val('');
});

DOMManager.getAllRescues();
```

Here is the full HTML code as well.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Animal Rescue App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="new-rescue">
        <h2>New Rescue</h2>
        <input type="text" id="new-rescue-name" class="form-control"><br>
        <button id="create-new-rescue" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Create</button>
    </div>
    <div id="app">

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add those dozen or so lines of code as text, rather than an image - by the way, none of that code would do a `POST` and `https://ancient-taiga-31359.herokuapp.com/api/houses` works as a GET request ... are you perhaps doing something wrong in the code you haven't shown?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JaromandaX I provided all of the code now.